Showing Recurring Dates Only Once in a View Using Smart Dates
Our site has an event content type that uses the Smart Dates module with the recurring submodule. On that site, we have a view which attempts to show the next week's upcoming events. Some events are recurring, and some are one-off instances. A few of the recurring events occur multiple times in a week like Monday through Thursday. In the view, which uses fields not teasers, we would like to show only the next upcoming occurrence of an event. So, for events that happen multiple times in a week it would only show the closest up-coming date. Is this possible to do?

Yeap, it is possible to do. It's Drupal. :)
The most precise ability to query data is via SQL queries. As you are working with Views here, a custom views filter plugin is the right way to do this. It is easy to write and you can modify your view result list via modifying the query.
See a good example for a custom views filter plugin here (I adapted it recently by myself): https://gorannikolovski.com/blog/custom-views-filter-plugin-drupal

That blog post is illuminating. It was helpful to walk through it, but my issue is a little more complicated. I can get all upcoming events by filtering for "Content: Date - End" is greater than or equal to "now" and less than or equal to "+7 days". However, for the recurring events, each instance is returned as a separate entry along with other non-recurring events. I want to keep the ones that do not have multiple occurrences and filter the ones that do by keeping only the one closest to now. I can filter the post execute results but then I have to return a large number of rows.

If you cannot query it via SQL, nothing can do it. I would really suggest that you translate your expectations into the query. Custom filter plugins are really strong in combining views with your custom sql queries.
